# Cannot assign/cast PostgreSQL record with JSONB to an HSTORE column

Tags: postgresql, casting, record, jsonb, hstore

I'm trying to create a `trash` table, where I can store deleted entities, and have the ability to restore them manually as needed. To make this more complicated, my tables have `JSONB`, `HSTORE`, `GEOMETRY`, and `BYTEA` columns.

Inserting is pretty simple:

```sql
insert into trash (original_table, original_id, content) select 'something', id, to_jsonb(something) from something where ...;
```

But HSTORE seems to cause problems when I'm trying to read data back from `trash`:

```sql
select t.* from trash, jsonb_to_record(content) as t(id bytea, created_at timestamp, attributes hstore, ...);
```

(`content` is a column of type `JSONB`.)

`GEOMETRY`, `BYTEA`, and `JSONB` columns get assigned/cast just fine. I know that `JSONB` cannot be automatically cast to `HSTORE`, so I created this `CAST`:

```sql
CREATE FUNCTION jsonb_to_hstore(j JSONB) RETURNS HSTORE IMMUTABLE STRICT LANGUAGE sql AS $$
    SELECT hstore(array_agg(key), array_agg(value)) FROM jsonb_each_text(j)
$$;

CREATE CAST (JSONB AS HSTORE) WITH FUNCTION jsonb_to_hstore AS IMPLICIT;
```

But it doesn't seem to be used, and I still get this error when including the `HSTORE` column in `t(...)`:

```
ERROR:  Syntax error near '"' at position 11
```

Why is my cast not used by `AS`? Where can I find out more about the usage of the `record` type? `jsonb_to_record` documentation mentions that:

> As with all functions returning `record`, the caller must explicitly define the structure of the record with an `AS` clause.

But I can't find anything more about this.